# I can't start gunicorn on AWS EC2

Tags: python, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn, django-mysql

I was going to update to using sqlite database into the mysql database on my django project.
after replaced settings.py like bellow:

`   DATABASES = {

```
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': '*',
       'USER': '*',
       'PASSWORD': '*',
       'HOST': 'localhost',
       'PORT': '***',

   }
```

}

then I excuted this command `systemctl restart gunicorn`

here is the screenshot:

[EC2 screebshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kWIq.png)

Comment: I followed this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database,     and also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html,   but same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check Nginx configuration on your OS.
The error says that the configuration was incorrect.